# Update Created By and Modified By using CSOM when only knowing their e-mail

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have their Office 365 E-Mail and I need to have the Created By and Modified By columns refer to their user.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve it myself

```
var user = clientContext.Web.SiteUsers;
User targetUser = user.GetByEmail(creatorMail);
newItem["Author"] = targetUser;
newItem["Editor"] = targetUser;
newItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a caveats when you update Author and Editor field in CSOM for SharePoint Online. I had inconsistent results so I wrote my discovery in the article:
https://ikmoss.wordpress.com/2019/04/29/issues-when-updating-created-by-and-modified-by-fields-in-sharepoint-online-csom/